# Tricky integral with fraction in exponent

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble solving the following integral:

$ \int_a^b x^{3.6} exp(-a x) dx $

(a is a constant in $\mathbb{R}$)

I'm not getting very far with substitution or integration by parts.

On wikipedia I found formulas for $ \int_0^1 x^{n} exp(-a x) dx $ and $ \int_0^\infty x^{n} exp(-a x) dx $ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ respectively, but it doesn't say how they are derived. 
Plus, I really need the fraction in the exponent.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the integral can be rewritten to: $\int_{a}^{b}{x^{3.6}e^{(-ax)}}dx$. If so, used IBP or the table method as a consequence of IBP.

Comment: The "incomplete gamma function" is defined as $\Gamma(a,x)=\int_x^{\infty} t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt$.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html

Comment: The integrand does not seem to have a closed-form antiderivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a>0$. As in my comment above, the "incomplete gamma function" is defined as: 
$$ \Gamma(a,x) = \int_x^{\infty} t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt $$
By substitution (using $t=ax$), this gives: 
$$ \int_{c}^d x^{3.6}e^{-ax}dx = \frac{\Gamma(4.6,ac)-\Gamma(4.6, ad)}{a^{4.6}}$$

---

More on the incomplete gamma function is here: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html

---

You can also get a series solution by the expansion $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$.  The case $a=0$ can also be solved easily.

Comment: Thanks. I would not have arrived at that by myself.
I tried to follow your solution and now I'm arriving at $(\Gamma(4.6, ad) - \Gamma(4.6, ac))/a^{4.6}$ ... ?

Comment: I'm assuming $a>0$ and $0<c<d$. So $\Gamma(4.6,ac)-\Gamma(4.6,ad) = \int_{ac}^{\infty} - \int_{ad}^{\infty}= \int_{ac}^{ad} t^{3.6}e^{-t}dt$.

Comment: It should be $\int_{ac}^{ad} = \int^{\infty}_{ad} - \int^{\infty}_{ac}$. Anyway thanks for the great reply!!! I had no clue before.

Comment: Sorry, you're of course right about the limits. Never mind ;)